# remover arquivos de dentro do container depois do build. Tem como fazer?

Tags: build, docker

como excluir arquivos depois do build? estou "buildando" uma imagem com uma chave do google cloud, so que eu nao posso deixar essa chave dentro do container, por motivos de segurança. O problema é que se eu nao por ela, o google cloud nao vai autenticar. Ou existe outra forma de eu autenticar a key do google cloud de fora do container?

Answer (score 1):

[Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) é uma feature do docker desenhada exatamente para este cenário, no entanto ela faz algo ligeiramente diferente. Em vez de remover arquivos, você só copia para o último estágio os arquivos binários, deixando todos os demais arquivos nos estágios anteriores. A imagem resultante contém apenas o último estágio, todos os predecessores só existem durante o build.